# Setting chapquote, formatting

Tags: horizontal-alignment, quoting

How could I align author completely to the right? Or even better, could you show me which commands to play with? I have this in preamble:

```
\makeatletter                                       
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][2.7em]
  {\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}
   \def\chapquote@author{#2}
   \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax
   \itshape}
  {\newline\par\normalfont\hfill--\ \chapquote@author\hspace*{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip}
\makeatother
```

and then:

```
\begin{document}

  \chapter{Question}

    \begin{chapquote}
              {Name Surname, \textit{Book name} \cite{Handler}}
              ,,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet foo bar.''
    \end{chapquote}
```

results in this:

[image]

I see, that when I play with the "em" value in the command below, I can set the padding from right and left at the same time (or something like this). But I'd like to set it separately from right and left. Could you help/navigate me?

Thank you

> \newenvironment{chapquote}[2][**1em**]

Answer (score 1):

Here, I introduce an extra argument to `chapquote`.  If it (first mandatory argument) is blank, then right margin is same as left (the optional argument).  If the 1st mandatory argument is non-blank, it uses the optional argument for the left margin and the first mandatory argument for the right margin.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\makeatletter                                       
\newenvironment{chapquote}[3][2.7em]
  {\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}
   \ifx\relax#2\relax\setlength{\@tempdimb}{#1}\else\setlength{\@tempdimb}{#2}\fi
   \def\chapquote@author{#3}
   \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-\@tempdima-\@tempdimb\relax
   \itshape}
  {\newline\par\normalfont\hfill--\ \chapquote@author\hspace*{\@tempdimb}\par\bigskip}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \chapter{Question}

    \begin{chapquote}{150pt}
              {Name Surname, \textit{Book name} \cite{Handler}}
              ,,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet foo bar.''
    \end{chapquote}

    \begin{chapquote}{}
              {Name Surname, \textit{Book name} \cite{Handler}}
              ,,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet foo bar. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet foo bar. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet foo bar. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet foo bar.''
    \end{chapquote}

    \begin{chapquote}{0pt}
              {Name Surname, \textit{Book name} \cite{Handler}}
              ,,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet foo bar. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet foo bar. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet foo bar. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet foo bar.''
    \end{chapquote}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one indeed wanted the *default* right margin to be 0pt, rather than the same as the left margin, then this one line needs alteration:

```
\ifx\relax#2\relax\setlength{\@tempdimb}{0pt}\else\setlength{\@tempdimb}{#2}\fi
```